# Building a chrome extension that scrapes data from a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I want to try building a chrome extension, but I just wanted to ask around to make sure it was actually possible first, as I have never built a chrome extension before.

My idea for the extension is that it finds and returns prices of commodities from the frontpage of a site and then displays this information depending on what commodities the user wishes to see.

This is rather vague, but this is pretty much all that needs to be done. I thought this could definitely be done, but I am starting to doubt myself after seeing some other posts saying things like it would not be possible if the tab wasn't open to that page.

Feedback on the feasibility of this would be appreciated.

Also would any languages besides HTML/CSS and JS be needed to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: You want a chrome extension that does that in the background without the site being open? I don't think [CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681292/same-origin-policy-and-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing) will let you do that.

Comment: ... apparently [you can](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/xhr).

Comment: Yes that would be the intention.

Comment: Simply making those requests from the extensions [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) would do the job. And no, you don't require knowledge of other languages to create a simple chrome extension.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6508393/9867451

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web Scraping in a Google Chrome Extension (JavaScript + Chrome APIs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508393/web-scraping-in-a-google-chrome-extension-javascript-chrome-apis)