# is it possible to do some simple web scraping in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension

thanks in advance and Im sorry if this might not be a well formed question, I am relatively new to CS and stackoverflow.

I am hoping to make a simple chrome extension, which overrides the new tab page to display some simple data collected from a couple websites. I am wondering if it is possible to web scrape within the basic JS or chrome API's? Any information or guidance would be greatly appreciated, I have been trying to do research on the subject and haven't found any recent or clear answers to this.

Thanks for your help!

Here is an older stackoverflow question asking the same question but I wasn't able to make any progress from the answers.

[Web Scraping in a Google Chrome Extension (JavaScript + Chrome APIs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508393/web-scraping-in-a-google-chrome-extension-javascript-chrome-apis)

Answer (score 6):

Absolutely and not just simple scraping.

If you think about it using the browser itself is as close as possible to replicating a real user session. You don't have to care about manually setting cookies, discover and construct json http requests. The browser does it all for you. After a page has been rendered (with or without javascript) you can access the DOM and extract any content you like.

Take a look at https://github.com/get-set-fetch/extension, an open source browser extension that does more than just basic scraping. It supports infinite scrolling, clicking and extracting content from single page javascript apps.

Disclaimer: I'm the extension author.

If you're serious about the subject start by developing a simple chrome extension (from my own experience Chrome throws more verbose extension errors than Firefox): https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Take a look afterwards at the main get-set-fetch background plugins: FetchPlugin (loads an url in a tab and waits for the DOM to stabilize), ExtractUrlPLugin (identifies additional urls to scrape from the current url), ExtractHtmlContentPlugin (actual scraping based on CSS selectors).

There are downsides though. It’s a lot easier to run a scraping script in your favorite language dumping the scraped content into a database than automatically starting the browser, loading the extension, controlling the extension, exporting scraped data to a format like csv, importing that data into a database.

In my opinion, it only makes sense to use a browser extension if you don’t want to automate the data extraction or the page you’re trying to scrape is so javascript heavy it’s easier to automate the extension than writing a scraping script.

Comment: Great, thanks for the advice, I will definitely look into everything you recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the extension.  I’m looking to create an extension to supplement my web app that scraps data from a users 3rd party account they access.  Basically my site takes reports they download and analyze the data. I would like to do an extension thag allows them to scrape/import the data directly to eliminate the need to download and upload reports.  Seems like this extension is probably the boilerplate I need to do this.

Answer (score -1):

> I am wondering if it is possible to web scrape within the basic JS or chrome API's?

Yes, use `fetch` to call REST APIs.